# Magento backend: How to add jscolor?

Tags: javascript, magento, backend, color-picker

I am trying to add a colorpicker in the backend of Magento. So far i have probabaly the class. (see below). But i have no idea how the Data.php file should look like. an anyone help or give me an example?

Greets

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Colorpicker extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
{
    $url  = Mage::getBaseUrl('js');
    $element->addClass("color");
    $output = "";
    if(!defined("_LOADED_JSCOLOR_")){
        $jspath = $url.'jscolor/jscolor.js';
        $output .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$jspath.'"></script>';
        define("_LOADED_JSCOLOR_",1);
    }
    $output .= $element->getElementHtml();
    return $output;
}
```

}

Comment: Not very sure about this, buy you can include the `<script></script>` directly in the phtml files afaik

Answer (score 1):

You can add js file to layout update:

```
<action method="addJs"><file>%folder%/%file%.js</file></action>
```

Answer (score 1):

A module I am building would be great if I could have admin config fields use JSColor. I came across this post, looked at the simple setup for JSColor, and whaddya know, this is pretty much already built-in to Magento (at least as of version 1.7.0.2).

If you have an admin layout update file, simply include:

```
<adminhtml_system_config_edit>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>jscolor/jscolor.js</file></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_edit>
```

In testing this out, I discovered that the JSColor script is already included in the 1.7.0.2 package. `/js/jscolor/jscolor.js`.

From there, it's as simple as assigning the `color` class to the input form field. I'm not sure if this is intended or not, but this is as simple as adding a `<validate>` node to your `system.xml` file.

```
<fields>
    <bg>
        <label>Background Color</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <validate>color</validate>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </bg>
</fields>
```

Horray! Nothing else to customize... no custom `<frontend_type>` necessary... nothing... Include the script, give it a class of `color` via the `<validate>` node, and you're done!